# Calculating number of strings

Tags: combinatorics

I am stuck on this problem I think I need to use the "Inclusion-Exclusion" principle to solve I am hoping that someone could give me some useful pointers.

I have a string of length 100 and each character of the string is a digit or a lower case letter. This string has 3 rules that it cannot start with qwe, and it cannot end with thl, and it cannot start with 5709.

So what I have done so far is:

All possible characters is 10 (digits) + 26 (lower case characters) = 36.

So first rule there are A: 36^97 possible combinations, second rule there are B: 36^97 cominations, and third rule there are C: 36^96 combinations.

Then using inclusion-exclusion rule I do

$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C|$
= 36^97 + 36^97 + 36^96 - (36^94) - (36^97) - (36^93)

This doesnt seem right to me

Comment: How did you come up with $36^{97}$ strings that *begin* with qwe and also *begin* with 5709. My count is considerably smaller than that!

Comment: I came up with 36^97 because you can't start the string with abc. I also add 36^96 for the strings that dont start with 5709. Later I subtract the overlap with 36^93 which are the strings that are dont start with abc and 5097. Maybe I am reading the problem incorrectly :S

Comment: Okay - you are more turned around than I thought. I thought you were trying to calculate the number of strings that can't be formed, which you would then subtract from the total number of strings. That is workable. Your approach is not. All of your counts are bad. There are $36^{97}$ strings that *do* start with "abc" (or "qwe", like in the original problem statement), For strings that *don't* start with "abc", the number is $36^{100} - 36^{97}$.

Comment: I think I worked it out. Its 36^100 - 36^97 - 36^97 - 36^94 for string that don't start with abc, and don't end with xyz, and don't start with 5709. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite that easy. There are strings that start with abc and end with xyz. You are currently subtracting those twice, and similarly for strings beginning with 5709 and ending with xyz.

Comment: so then  36^100 - 36^97 - 36^97 - 36^96 + (36^94) + (36^97) + (36^93)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29256/discussion-between-steph-and-paul-sinclair).

Comment: And again you've counted $36^{97}$ strings that begin with both abc and 5709. How is that possible?

Comment: I think that the fifth term $-36^{97}$ in your sum should be $0$ because these events cannot occur together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have sets:

\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=& \text{"Strings starting with 'qwe'"} \\
B &=& \text{"Strings ending with 'thl'"} \\
C &=& \text{"Strings starting with '5709'".} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

You want the number of strings belonging to none of these sets, which is:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left| A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c\right| &=& \left|\left( A\cup B\cup C\right)^c\right| \\
&=& |\Omega| - (|A|+|B|+|C|) + (|A\cap B| + |A\cap C| + |B\cap C|) - |A\cap B\cap C| \\
&&\qquad\text{by Inclusion-Exclusion} \\
&=& 36^{100} - (36^{97} + 36^{97} + 36^{96}) + (36^{94} + 0 + 36^{93}) - 0 \\
&=& 36^{100} - 2\times 36^{97} - 36^{96} + 36^{94} + 36^{93}.
\end{eqnarray*}

$$\\$$

Another approach to the problem is to break the $100$ characters into:

- the first $4$
- the next $93$
- the last $3$

and count the number of ways each component doesn't break any rule.

- "First $4$" can occur in $36^{4} - 36 - 1$ ways: $36$ break rule $A$ ('qwe*') and $1$ breaks rule $C$ ('5709').
- "Next $93$" can occur in $36^{93}$ ways.
- "Last $3$" can occur in $36^{3} - 1$ ways: 'thl' breaks rule $B$.

So the required number is the product of these three values:

$$(36^{4} - 37)(36^{93})(36^{3} - 1)$$

which equals the result above.

Comment: This makes perfect sense and in fact I think you can do some simplifications (correct me if I am wrong). I was originally visualizing a ven diagram were all 3 circle connect. But in fact I think that the sets A and B connect and the sets B and C connect. Therefore I think the equation would be:

$|U| - (|A| + |B| + |C|) + |A \cap B| + |B \cap C|$

Comment: @Steph Yes, that's right. I included all combinations in the formula for clarity and completeness and then showed two of them as having $0$ value in the next line. But you can also simplify as you've done - that's fine.